# how to multi filtering vue.js

Tags: vue.js, filtering

just new in vue.js.
I have an `array` of `objects` which is my `products`, How to multi filter it?

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" required v-model="selectedCategory" value="1"> // Category 1
<input type="checkbox" required v-model="selectedCategory" value="2"> // Category 2

<div>
   <div v-for="product in filteredProducts">
      <a href="#">                          
         <div class="prdct-frame__img-holder">
            <img :src="product.productImage">
         </div>
         <p>{{ product.productName }}</p>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
        var vm = new Vue({
            el:  "#main",
            data: {
                products: [
                    {
                        productName: "Product 1",   
                        productID: 1,
                        productImage: //via.placeholder.com/200x200,
                        categoryID: true,// 1
                        colorID: 1, //blue
                        sizeID: 1, //large
                    },
                    {
                        productName: "Product 2",   
                        productID: 2,
                        productImage: //via.placeholder.com/200x200,
                        categoryID: true, // 1
                        colorID: 2, //red
                        sizeID: 2, //medium
                    },
                    {
                        productName: "Product 3",   
                        productID: 3,
                        productImage: //via.placeholder.com/200x200,
                        categoryID: true, // 2
                        colorID: 3, //green
                        sizeID: 3, //small
                    },
                    {
                        productName: "Product 4",   
                        productID: 4,
                        productImage: //via.placeholder.com/200x200,
                        categoryID: true, // 2
                        colorID: 4, //green
                        sizeID: 3, //small
                    },
                ],
                selectedCategory: [],
            },
            computed: {
                filteredProducts: function() {

                    var vm = this;
                    var category = vm.selectedCategory;

                    return vm.products.filter((product) => {
                        var keys = Object.keys(product);
                        var matchFilter = false;
                        category.forEach((key) => {
                            if(product[key] === true) {
                                matchFilter = true;
                            }
                        });
                        return matchFilter;
                    });             

                },

            }
        });
    </script>
```

This Code works for filtering by category, if I filter by `Category 1` it display all the `products` under `Category 1` which is right. Now I want to filter it too by `color` and `size`.

For example if choose `Category 1` and choose color is `red` and choose size is `medium`
The expected out put will be :
Product name : `Product 2`
Color : `red`
Size : `medium`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I really don't see how your claim the category filter is working could be true. All your products have `categoryId: true`. How do you differentiate between products of category 1 and those of category 2?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your attention, well I put true as a value for filtering. if the selected category === true. also I put comments for the actual value

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Array of filters:

```js
data()
{
  return {
    filtration:
    [
      {
        key: 'categoryID',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        key: 'colorID',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        key: 'sizeID',
        value: 2
      },
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
                filteredProducts: function() {
                    const arrFilters = this.filtration;
                    return this.products.filter((product) => {
                        return arrFilters.every((filter) => {
                            return product[filter.key] === filter.value;
                        });
                    });             

                },

            }
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your attention, would you mind to show me where exactly put that code? your response means to me.